# BleachBit on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS after updating

Tags: command-line, updates, bleachbit

I run auto clean, clean package list, auto remove, etc, in the top section of bleach bit and sudo apt-get clean after I update ubuntu, will running these commands uninstall the updates, or does it get rid of old unneeded kernels/package lists? Just wanted to verify that running these commands do not uninstall the updates, after I ran these, the system says it is up to date, just wanted to verify that these commands do not uninstall updates?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic specifically states "Questions that you may ask... Running third-party applications on Ubuntu" so I am puzzled why anyone would vote to close this.

Answer (score 0):

I've run it multiple times on multiple systems, and it did not uninstall updates.

Comment: i can't seem to run bleach bit as non-root user, I can only run it as root, what may be the cause?

Comment: That's a different issue, and belongs in a different question. As per https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask "Your questions should be reasonably scoped." However, https://docs.bleachbit.org/doc/frequently-asked-questions.html notes you _can_ run it as either administrator ('root') or as a normal user, so please refer to that weblink in your next question which asks this.